# Using Grails GORM standalone

Tags: orm, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm currently wondering how it is possible to use the Groovy ORM Layer from Grails standalone outside of the Grails Framework. There is a [Documentation Entry](http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+StandAlone+Gorm) for doing so, but the [ZIP file only links to an empty page](http://www.grails.org/%5Egorm-0.5.6.zip). I downloaded Grails 1.2-M3 but I couldn't find anything in the docs either.

Does anybody know what the current state is and how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK it is possible to use GORM standalone since Grails 1.1. 
This allows you to use GORM as your ORM without using the full Grails framework

However, I don't think it's possible to use GORM outside of Spring (which is the foundation on which Grails is built). To summarise:

- You can use GORM without using Grails
- You cannot use GORM without using Spring

A sample application demonstrating how to use GORM outside Grails is available [here](http://www.nabble.com/Standalone-GORM-td21548547.html). If you want to browse the source code of this example in a browser (instead of checking it out from the SVN repository), [start here](http://svn.grails.codehaus.org/browse/grails/branches/GRAILS_1_1/samples/petclinic-mvc).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I stumbled across the newsgroup entry but wasn't sure if it is already outdated. I'm using Spring in the project anyway so that requirement is no problem at all.

Comment: Please also see the 'Using GORM outside of Grails' (http://grails.org/GORM+-+StandAlone+Gorm) page on Grails Wiki.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question this page didn't really help, the link is broken and the information is outdated.

Comment: I DO use GORM without spring...

Answer (score 0):

As of Grails 2.3.6, GORM is officially supported as a standalone module.  See the [release notes](http://grails.org/2.3.6+Release+Notes) for more details.