# Can I build a grails project into a stand-alone jar and use it from a Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, grails

We are using a opensource grails project, we want to integrate it with our systems using message queues.

We can add our code for the message queues to the grails project. But what we would prefer to do is get the grails project to build a stand-alone jar file that we can then use from our project.

In our application we would want to initiate the hibernate/GORM layer of the opensource grails project, we don't need to the web layers as we are using messaging.

Ideally we would like our project to be a Spring/Java, however if this not practical then we would use a grails project.

Is any of this possible, or are they better ways to extend an existing grails project?

Comment: You mean [embedding groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy)?

Comment: Probably need grooby as I need GORM to handle the domain classes defined in the open source project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box way of reusing a Grails application in a Spring/Java application, although there are ways to use GORM standalone in a Spring application ([as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636664/using-grails-gorm-standalone))

My advice would be to extend the Grails application. If Groovy or certain Grails features are not desirable, you can still work with the project as if it was a plain Java-based Spring project by adding Java sources to `src/java`, using a separate `beans.xml` Spring bean configuration file and other "fallbacks".

Comment: I have done this already, but we don't need to fire up the full grails application as we're only interested in running our message queue interface. So looking for a way of re-using the business layer and domain layer and not having to run up the web services and security layers. If it can't be done, then we need to run the whole application.